# Vite build question (using laravel 9 project)

Tags: laravel, npm, vite

[App.scss to style.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvtDx.png)

Hello, I am making a laravel 9 project and I would like to know how to tell my vite to compile my app.scss into style.css within its specific folder. rather than it create a new file under a build folder.

```
`export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: 'public/css/',
               
        
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel([
            'resources/sass/app.scss',
            
            'resources/js/app.js',
            
        ]),
    ]
});`
```

this is my current vite.config.

I've tried several options on here but nothing seems to work.

Note: This is laravel 9. I had to install bootstrap aswell as vite so all the configs were default.

[This is what it does instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmHdC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `buildDirectory` option in `laravel-vite` plugin like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
 
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            hotFile: 'storage/vite.hot', // Customize the "hot" file...
            buildDirectory: 'bundle', // Customize the build directory...
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'], // Specify the entry points...
        }),
    ],
    build: {
      manifest: 'assets.json', // Customize the manifest filename...
    },
});
```

See for details:

- [Laravel documentation - Asset Bundling (Vite) Advanced Customization](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#advanced-customization)
- [Laravel Vite Plugin source code reference](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/src/index.ts#L27)

Comment: This just deletes my style.css and creates a new file in an asset folder under my CSS folder with an app-###### generated name

Comment: code taken from laravel documentation. use `buildDirectory` and `input` options.  add css file in input option array like this: `input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js']`.

Comment: I've done that, I just want the build to overwrite my current CSS file rather than create a new one via build. I've been just renaming and replacing after a build I guess I'll just have to stick with that. tedious.

Comment: `I just want the build to overwrite my current CSS file rather than create a new one via build.`

Compiled css files are minified and obfuscated to using serve in production apps. When you overwrite `edit file` with `compiled file`, how do you edit css file in future developments. Separation of development files with build files is important. Don't think overriding. It's not right way.

Comment: The file being over written is not the edit file. The file I want overwritten is the previous compiled file. my vite compiles a scss file to a CSS file, I still have my scss file to edit and recompile after, the file remains untouched. when I run the build vite compiles my scss to CSS and gives it a generated name I would like for it to be a set name rather than a random generated name given by the build process. for example the build generates a name like "app-q324324.css" I would like for it to keep the name "style.css" when the compile is finished.

Comment: Laravel adds hash value to build files for versioning concerns. You can change `don't use hash` option in vite config but you don't need that. Laravel's `manifest.json` file keeps map of these names when include asset files in blade templates. Check these: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles

Answer (score 0):

You can specify in the config what names to use for the chunks:

```
export default defineConfig({ 
//config options
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            chunkFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].js',
            assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[hash].[ext]',
        },
    }
},
//more config options
})
```

`[name]` is the current file name

`[hash]` is the hash of the current file

`[ext]` is the target extension of the current file (for example scss->css)

If you remove `[hash]` then you will be left with just the file name. (Thats what you wanted). Anyhow, this will leave you without versioning.

You can also set it up to not use hash-es in development and only use hashes in production

```
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
export default defineConfig({ 
//config options
build: {
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            chunkFileNames: isProduction
                ? 'assets/[hash].js'
                : 'assets/[name].js',
            assetFileNames: isProduction
                ? 'assets/[hash].[ext]'
                : 'assets/[name].[ext]',
        },
    }
},
//more config options
})
```

Combinig this with `@vite` injecting the right file into your blade file using the *manifest.json* with
`@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss','resources/js/app.js'])` is a good option.

Or you can import your SCSS file in *app.js* : `import '../sass/app.scss'`